# Erro ao capturar response do método shorten do TinyURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Preciso capturar o retorno do método `shorten` da biblioteca `TinyUrl`. Estou tentando armazenar esse retorno na variável `shortUrl` para depois salvar no banco da seguinte maneira:

```
import TinyUrl from 'tinyurl';

let shortUrl = '';

    TinyUrl.shorten(req.body.url, function (response, error) {
      if (error) console.log(error);
      console.log(response);
      shortUrl = response;
    });

    // Tudo certo para CRIAR o Site
    const { id, hits, url, short_url } = await Site.create({
      hits: 0,
      url: req.body.url,
      short_url: shortUrl,
    });

    return res.json({
      id,
      hits,
      url,
      short_url,
    });
```

Ao exibir `console.log(response);` é exibido corretamente o retorno desejado, porém a variável `shortUrl` não é setada. Como posso fazer ?

Comment: A resposta do método `shorten` é assíncrona, você deveria mover toda a lógica para dentro do callback, ou então pegar o retorno do método, que é uma promise, e esperar pela sua resolução com `await`.

Comment: como ficaria a implementação ?

Comment: `const shortUrl = await TinyUrl.shorten(req.body.url)`

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemente da seguinte maneira:

```
const shortUrl = await TinyUrl.shorten(req.body.url);

// Tudo certo para CRIAR o Site
const { id, hits, url, short_url } = await Site.create({
  hits: 0,
  url: req.body.url,
  short_url: shortUrl,
});
```